# Add a Javascript Link to an Entire Flexbox Item

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, href

I'm trying to make an entire flexbox item clickable, which is pointing at some javascript. As i'm using javascript to pull in content below the flexbox container there are multiple IDs within the structure to consider.

At the moment i'm only able to make the text clickable rather than the entire .div and if I move the link it breaks the flexbox from scaling.

There are some other similar questions on here, but because of the javascript none of the answers seem to be work.

I've added the code that i'm using here https://jsfiddle.net/xv3emywb/, and also pasted it below. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="offer-flex-container";>

<div id="solutions-anchor-div" class="offer-flex-item">
<a id="solutions-anchor" href="javascript:;">Solutions</a>
</div>

<div id = "services-anchor-div" class="offer-flex-item">
<a id="services-anchor" href="javascript:;">Services</a>
</div>

<div id="lifecycle-anchor-div" class="offer-flex-item">
<a id="lifecycle-anchor" href="javascript:;">Lifecycle</a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.offer-flex-container{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
-ms-box-orient: horizontal;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -moz-flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.offer-flex-item{
background: #150f2a;
margin-right: 2px;
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
line-height: 100px;
color: white;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 60px;
}
```

And the javascript that i'm using to load content below the .div once the link has been selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#solutions-content").show();
  $("#services-content").hide();
  $("#lifecycle-content").hide();
  $("#solutions-anchor-div").css("background","#2fb4c8");

   $("#solutions-anchor").click(function(){
       $("#services-content").hide();
       $("#solutions-content").show();
       $("#lifecycle-content").hide();
       $("#solutions-anchor-div").css("background","#2fb4c8");
       $("#services-anchor-div").css("background","#150f2a");
       $("#lifecycle-anchor-div").css("background","#150f2a");

    });

  $("#services-anchor").click(function(){
        $("#services-content").show();
        $("#solutions-content").hide();
        $("#lifecycle-content").hide();
        $("#services-anchor-div").css("background","#2fb4c8");
        $("#solutions-anchor-div").css("background","#150f2a");
        $("#lifecycle-anchor-div").css("background","#150f2a");
   });

   $("#lifecycle-anchor").click(function(){
        $("#services-content").hide();
        $("#solutions-content").hide();
        $("#lifecycle-content").show();
        $("#services-anchor-div").css("background","#150f2a");
        $("#solutions-anchor-div").css("background","#150f2a");
        $("#lifecycle-anchor-div").css("background","#2fb4c8");
   });
 });
```

Comment: Well for starters, remove any _padding_ from the div containers - otherwise that will keep whatever clickable element you place inside “at bay” of course. And then, make the links `block` or `flex`, and add `height:100%` …

Comment: Ah perfect. Thank you @CBroe I knew there was a simple answer. As you can probably tell i'm new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CBroe for input.

The simple fix was to remove any padding from the div containers and add some styling to the link.

```
.offer-flex-item a{
display:block; 
height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because anchor tag is inline. So add below css code in css file and remove padding from ".offer-flex-item" class and it will work as expected.

```
.offer-flex-item a{
   display:block; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. That works perfectly once you combine it with height: 100% as well.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.offer-flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.offer-flex-item {
  background: #150f2a;
  margin-right: 2px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
}


.full-width-link a{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

a:hover{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-flex-container">

  <div id="solutions-anchor-div" class="offer-flex-item">
    <a id="solutions-anchor" href="javascript:;">Solutions</a>
  </div>

  <div id="services-anchor-div" class="full-width-link offer-flex-item">
    <a id="services-anchor" href="javascript:;">Services</a>
  </div>

  <div id="lifecycle-anchor-div" class="offer-flex-item">
    <a id="lifecycle-anchor" href="javascript:;">Lifecycle</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

I added an onhover class so you can see in this example what the surface of your link is. I also made the second element full size. However, still the padding of the parent element will be present.

Comment: Hi @WillemvanderVeen thanks for the input and the snippet. It looks like I also need to remove the padding-top from the .offer-flex-item in order for the second element to go full height. All seems to be working well once that's added! 

Thanks again.